# How do i pass variables into methods - java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods

I need to use a variable from one method in another. Here is the code:

```
public static void secondMain() {
        BufferedReader reader;
        var lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        var rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("rooms.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        lines.add(line);
        while (line != null) {
            line = reader.readLine();
            lines.add(line);

        }
        
        reader.close();
        
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size() - 1; i++){

            String[] words = lines.get(i).split(" ");
            var room = new Room();
            room.roomNum = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
            room.roomType = (words[1]);
            room.roomPrice = Double.parseDouble(words[2]);
            room.hasBalcony = Boolean.parseBoolean(words[3]);
            room.hasLounge = Boolean.parseBoolean(words[4]);
            room.eMail = (words[5]);
            rooms.add(room);    
                       
            }
```

Here is where it needs to be used:

```
public static void reserveRoom() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    String choice = "";
    
    do {
secondMain();
        System.out.println("\n-- ROOM RESERVATION --");
        System.out.println("Please enter the room number you wish to reserve");
        System.out.println("Q - Quit");
        Room selectedRoom = null;
         var searchRoomNum = input.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < rooms.size(); i++){                 
              if(rooms.get(i).roomNum == searchRoomNum){
                  selectedRoom = rooms.get(i);            
                    System.out.println("Room Number: " + selectedRoom.roomNum);
                    System.out.println("Room Type: " + selectedRoom.roomType);
                    System.out.println("Room Price: " + selectedRoom.roomPrice);
                    System.out.println("Balcony: " + selectedRoom.hasBalcony);
                    System.out.println("Lounge: " + selectedRoom.hasLounge);
                    System.out.println("Email: " + selectedRoom.eMail);
                    System.out.println("-------------------");
              }
         }
        
    }
```

my current error is on the for loop where im testing the conditions against the array. "rooms cannot be resolved".

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You define `rooms` in `secondMain` then expect to be able to use it in `reserveRoom` without ever passing it in.

Comment: where are you calling the function `reserveRoom()`?

Comment: @M.Abdel-Ghani the function reserveRoom() is called in my main method.

Comment: You Can return List<Room> from secondMain() and store it in a List<Room> in reserveRoom() method, this would be easy and more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access `rooms` from the `secondMain()` method in the `reserveRoom()`, you should return it from `secondMain()` when you make the call. This can be done by changing the return type of the method
`public static void secondMain()` to become `public static ArrayList<Room> secondMain()`

Then after the for loop in `secondMain()` when you have finished adding all the rooms to the array list, you should return `rooms` to the caller. This can be added as one statement after your try catch block.

```
return rooms;
```

This way you can access this property from `reserveRoom()`. The line where the call is made

```
do {
secondMain();
```

should become:

```
do{
var rooms = secondMain();
```

This should allow you to access rooms in `reserveRoom()`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `public static void secondMain`, you can make it `public static ArrayList<Room> secondMain`

At the end of the secondMain: `return rooms`.

In the `reserveRoom` method: when you call the secondMain method: `ArrayList<Room> rooms = secondMain();`

Now you should be able to use `rooms` inside `reserveRoom` method